# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'CaseDetailProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

For example:

```
type CaseDetailProps = {
  id: number,
  apply_degree?: string;
  year?: number;
}
```

```
const caseData: CaseDetailProps = {
   id: 1,
   apply_degree: 'b',
   year: 2020
}

const fields = ['id', 'apply_degree', 'year']

fields.forEach(r => {
    if(caseData?.[r]) {    // TODO: here have a problem
      // some code
    }
})
```

When I want to get  `caseData?.[r]`, VS Code has a problem: `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'CaseDetailProps'`

and I don't want bad ways to resolve this problem

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know that `r` is going to be a valid key? At the moment it's just some string, hence the error. Indeed one of them _isn't_, and if you told the compiler you expected `fields` to contain only valid properties of `CaseDetailProps` it could tell you that you haven't!

Answer (score -1):

you can use `keyof` to get the keys type of any interface.

```
type CaseDetailProps = {
  id: number,
  apply_degree?: string;
  year?: number;
}


type key = keyof CaseDetailProps;
const caseData: CaseDetailProps = {
   id: 1,
   apply_degree: 'b',
   year: 2020
}

const fields = ['id', 'degree', 'year'] as key[];

// const fields: key[] = ['id', 'degree', 'year']; // this will not allow 'degree' key, it does not exist in CaseDetailProps


fields.forEach(r   => {
    if(caseData?.[r]) {
      // some code
    }
})
```

Comment: The [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) `const fields = ['id', 'degree', 'year'] as key[];` is unsafe, as you'd see if you wrote the correct line `const fields: key[] = ['id', 'degree', 'year'];`

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes but if we do with the way you suggested it'll not support 'degree'. It does not exist in `CaseDetailProps`

Comment: Right, because that's **not** a property of the object. That's _useful information_! Don't lie to the compiler, let it tell you you're wrong, then it can actually help you find bugs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what if we want to check that also,

Comment: Why would we? We already know a `CaseDetailProps` doesn't have a `degree` property (that we care about), because if it did it would be _included in the type_. If you should be able to access arbitrary properties, then the index signature the error refers to is the right thing to do.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was assuming that also otherwise, I will also suggest the same.