# Accessing object with bracket notation gives Typescript error 7053

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

There are a bunch of similar questions, but none of them seem to address my exact scenario because I am trying to do it in JSX (well, TSX) and I don't think I can change the type when setting the parameter in my `map` method, as you will see. I have an object that contains arrays organized by type:

```
const ThingOptions = {
    animal: [
        {
            value: 'giraffe',
            content: ( <React.Fragment><br />has a long neck.</React.Fragment> ),
        },
        {
            value: 'lion',
            content: ( <React.Fragment><br />is ferocious</React.Fragment> ),
        },
    ],
    mineral: [
        {
            value: 'talc',
            content: ( <React.Fragment><br />is soft.</React.Fragment> ),
        },
        {
            value: 'iron',
            content: ( <React.Fragment><br />is metallic.</React.Fragment> ),
        },
    ],
};
```

I then wanted to refactor a component so that I didn't have two identical blocks of code with the only difference being `animal` or `mineral`, but I also didn't think it warranted a whole new component. This is what I tried in the component:

```
const thingTypes = ['animal', 'mineral'];

return (
    <div className="ConfigThings">
        {thingTypes.map((type, j) => (
            <ListGroup className={type} key={j.toString()}>
            {ThingOptions[type].map((option, i) => (        // <------ Error here
                <ListGroup.Item key={i.toString()} className={type}>
                    <Button
                        id={i.toString()}
                        value={option.value}
                        className={type}
                        onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.currentTarget.id, type)}
                    >
                        {option.value}
                    </Button>
                    {option.content}
                </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
            </ListGroup>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

The error I get is:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ animal: { value: string; content: Element; }[]; mineral: { value: string; content: Element; }[]; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ animal: { value: string; content: Element; }[]; mineral: { value: string; content: Element; }'.ts(7053)
```

I get the error since `type` is just a string and could be out of range, but I don't see an elegant way out of this. The suggestions I have seen include trying something like `{thingTypes.map((type as keyof ThingOptions, j) => (` but even if it worked (which it doesn't) it would mess up `type` for all the places I use it as a string. I've tried many different permutations of typing `type` to no avail. Likewise I can't mark it as a `const` or anything, so I'm not sure if there is an actual solution for this that doesn't involve just breaking it into a new component, although I'm now very interested in a possible solution from at least an academic standpoint.

Comment: Here's a dupe from just yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70592608/3001761. Same comment: how does the compiler know that the contents of a `string[]` are all valid keys? Given that you know that they are, tell it by annotating the definition of `thingTypes`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ahhhh I see. I had seen that but was missing something crucial. I had to have `type key = keyof typeof ThingOptions;` in order to use `const thingTypes: key[] = ['animal', 'mineral'];` - I was missing the `typeof`. Any chance you could point me to where I might have found this in the documentation? I am having difficulty finding things myself, but I'm trying hard to get better at helping myself. Also if you like to change the comment to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.